# Auto activate an item on select in a ListView

Tags: c#, listview

Is it possible that in a ListView whenever an Item has been selected (e.g mouse 1 left click or Key down or key up, left right) that item gets activated (Like when you hit enter or double click!). What event or properties of ListView will do this, if any?

**UPDATE**

I found out it will work if ListView.Activation is set to OneClick but thi is only for the mouse, I want the same with keyboard arrows too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by listening the the [ItemSelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged.aspx) event and simply calling the code that runs whenever an item is double-clicked.

Alternatively you can call [ItemActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemactivate.aspx) event that fires when an item is double-clicked using this bit of code, although I'd recommend the first method:

```
private void ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(Object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    ListView1_ItemActivate(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Just remember that ItemSelectionChanged is fired both when an item is selected *and* when it is deselected. Check the IsSelected property on the event args block to respond only when an item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You, have mouseclick and mousedoubleclick events in the listview control for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following events with whatever you want your listview to do.

KeyDown , KeyUp, KeyPress, MouseDown, MouseUp, MousePress, MouseHover, MouseEnter, MouseClick, MouseDoubleClick

those are only a few select examples.

Lets say your listview is named listView1

to Subscribe to one of the events, do this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(listView1_KeyDown);
}

void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Enter your content at the throw statement